Could not translate host name "jdbc:postgresql" in Django and Python
I've successfully created a Django project in Pycharm to talk to the default Sqlite3.  But now I'd like to switch to Postgress.  I have the following in settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}

But I get this error when trying to run
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" to address: Name or service not known

I get the same error when trying to run migrate, which I assume is necessary to create the tables

Did you review the Django docs and the various settings and pages?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-HOST

The issue is here 'HOST': 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres', .  1) JDBC is JAVA and you are working in Python. 2) That is a URI not a host value. 3) Read the docs Database settings.

Thanks.  I had gotten the url from the Pycharm data source

Obviously PyCharm is using JDBC behinds the scenes. 1) You are working with Django which does not . 2) Use the Django documentation not the PyCharm documentation. Follow the Django database connection links shown in previous comments.

HOST should just be "localhost".
Unrequested advice:  you probably don't want Django creating tables in the Postgres database.  Better to create another database and point Django to that.

It would be clearer to say don't use the postgres database in the Postgres cluster, instead create a new user defined  database in the cluster.

The purpose of the DATABASE dictionary is to pass all the specifics to their respective keys as required. There is no need to pass along the connection string here like this. Passing just localhost here should be enough.
